# Entity Framework Select() hide the data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to select all unique (expired dates) using `Distinct()` :

```
gridView3.Columns[0].FieldName = "pis_ExpireDate";

var EXdates = DB0201.purchases_item_seriels
                    .Where(u => (u.stitems_ID == ItemID && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID && u.pis_Statues == 0) ||
                                (u.stitems_ID == ItemID && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID && u.pis_Statues == 5) ||
                                (u.stitems_ID == ItemID && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID && u.pis_Statues == 6))
                    .OrderBy(o => o.pis_ExpireDate)
                    .Select(u => u.pis_ExpireDate).Distinct(); 

gridControl3.DataSource = EXdates.ToList();
```

Rows are created but no data appears!

I tried to select all data without `Select(u => u.pis_ExpireDate)` and it works

I need to show only list of expired dates in Gridview, I use this line to define the first column field name :

```
gridView3.Columns[0].FieldName = "pis_ExpireDate";
var EXdates = DB0201.purchases_item_seriels
                    .Where(u => (u.stitems_ID == ItemID && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID && u.pis_Statues == 0) ||
                                (u.stitems_ID == ItemID && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID && u.pis_Statues == 5) ||
                                (u.stitems_ID == ItemID && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID && u.pis_Statues == 6))
                    .OrderBy(o => o.pis_ExpiraeDate);
gridControl3.DataSource = EXdates.ToList();
```

Rows are created and all data is there.

Comment: Probably there is grid configuration - field mapping issue.

Comment: You didn't post the grid code (data binding, configuration) so one an only guess why the *grid* doesn't display what you want. It has nothing to do with EF though. The queries you posted return two completely different results. One returns single dates. The other returns complete rows. If you bind a list of dates to a grid that expects line items, you'll get multiple empty rows, simply because there are no values to display for any of the columns

Comment: `rows created and all data appear but without merge` what does that mean? There's no attempt to merge anything, in any of the queries. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i need to show only list of expired dates in Gridview , i use this line to define the first column field name : 
gridView3.Columns[0].FieldName = "pis_ExpireDate";

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not expect Merge to happen, but I wanted to show what I wanted. I apologize for that, I corrected the sentence.

Comment: @BassemKamalM there's no `pis_ExpireDate` in the first example. Assuming `pis_ExpireDate` is a DateTime youreturn a list of `DateTime` objects, not objects with `pis_ExpireDate` properties. The best option would be to remove the field name from the binding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos already explained it - the problem is that data binding expects a list of objecst having property called "pis_ExpireDate" while in the non working case you are feeding it with list of dates. I guess changing `.Select(u => u.pis_ExpireDate)` to `.Select(u => new { u.pis_ExpireDate })` would be enough.

Comment: @IvanStoev the binding statement was added after my comments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed. All I was saying is that you were right (your first comment) even before they did that :)

Comment: thank you , it work after changing to `.Select(u => new { u.pis_ExpireDate })` thanks @IvanStoev @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about grid configuration, but try this solution:

```
gridView3.Columns[0].FieldName = "pis_ExpireDate";

var EXdates = DB0201.purchases_item_seriels
    .Where( u => ( u.stitems_ID == ItemID 
                   && u.ss_StoreID == StoreID 
                   && (u.pis_Statues == 0 || u.pis_Statues == 5 || u.pis_Statues == 6 ) ))
    .OrderBy( o => o.pis_ExpiraeDate ).Distinct().Select( a => new { pis_ExpireDate = a } )
    .ToList();

gridControl3.DataSource = EXdates;
```

Updated bit query!

Comment: this error appear System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.purchases_item_serie_E5008677EB8BFE6A32656BA94B232411B2F01DA5D79EE4F711F972E15AC739D4' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Comment: thank you , it work after changing to `.Select(u => new { u.pis_ExpireDate })` thanks

Comment: @BassemKamalM Is it fine if I ask you to mark solution as "Answer"?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your query:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.pis_ExpireDate).Distinct();
```

Comment: This won't help at all. It will actuall make things worse. `GroupBy` returns `IGrouping<>` objects which *are* distinct by definition. They'll be unrecognizable by any grid configured to display row items

Comment: You can also create your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer` and pass it instance to Distinct() method.

Comment: Which would do *what*? It would still return an `IGrouping<T>` instead fo a list of T's , that can't be mapped to any grid.

Comment: empty grid view appear , no rows created